# How to drop (select) rows of a pandas dataframe according to certain criterions?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with quite a few members from different categories. The members are grouped together and sorted according to the score of each member in each category already. How can I keep only up to the top 3 members in each category ? (Sometimes the members in a category are less than 3. In that case, I want to keep all of them.)

For instance, the original dataframe is like this:

```
data = [['Tom', 'A', 10], ['Jack', 'A', 9], ['Andy', 'A', 8],
        ['Lily', 'A', 7], ['Johan', 'B', 10], ['Ewa', 'B', 9]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Category', 'Score'])
```

| student | category | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | A | 10 |
| Jack | A | 9 |
| Andy | A | 8 |
| Lily | A | 7 |
| Johan | B | 10 |
| Ewa | B | 9 |

The desired dataframe is:

| student | category | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | A | 10 |
| Jack | A | 9 |
| Andy | A | 8 |
| Johan | B | 10 |
| Ewa | B | 9 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the groupby function.
In your example :

```py
df_sorted.groupby('Category').head(3)
```

Take care, you may need to sort your dataframe before doing this groupby.
In your example :

```py
df.sort_values(by=['Category', 'Score'], ascending=[True, False])
```

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you use pandas groupby feature, more details you can find [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

Solution can be like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['Tom', 'A', 10], ['Jack', 'A', 9], ['Andy', 'A', 8],
    ['Lily', 'A', 7], ['Johan', 'B', 10], ['Ewa', 'B', 9]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Category', 'Score'])

top3_category = df.groupby('Category').head(3)
print(top3_category)
```